# Redirect feed with nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

I would like to redirect my feed to a feed service.

Using this, I can only redirect `mysite.com/feed` but not `mysite.com/feed/` (notice the slash after `feed`.

```
            if ($http_user_agent !~ "FeedValidator") {
                    rewrite ^/feed$ http://example.com/feed redirect;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
rewrite ^/feed$ http://example.com/feed redirect;
```

to:

```
rewrite ^/feed/?$ http://example.com/feed redirect;
```

This will make the slash optional.